# What's the purpose of the API key for Google Maps on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

For my general knowledge, I just wondered what was the purpose of the API key for Google Maps on Android.
I guess it allows Google to block abusive uses of their API but is it the only purpose of it? Does it have a point for developers?
Finally, why using Google Maps API on iOS doesn't require an API key?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on it:
[Obtaining a Google Maps Android API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

> "MapView objects are views that display Maps tiles downloaded from the Google Maps service. To ensure that applications use Maps data in an appropriate manner, the Google Maps service requires application developers to register with the service, agreeing to the Terms of Service and supplying an MD5 fingerprint of the certificate(s) that they will use to sign applications."

It is basically to hold the developer accountable for misuse.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Too bad it answers only to a part of my question

Comment: Good question. iOS MapKit does not need it apparently. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides, keeping the respective firm/developer accountable for any misuse, Google keeps track on how many maps are getting loaded by a particular application. Initial usage is free of charge. After a fixed no. of serving, it charges the company certain amount.